# Shebang executable not found because of UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark)

Tags: python, bash

For some reason the shebang in one of my scripts does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print "Hello World"
```

When I execute this file, I get an error

```
 % ./test.py
./test.py: 1: #!/usr/bin/env: not found
```

There is no problem with the content of my `/usr/bin/` directory: both `env` and `python` are there, with correct execution rights.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to how Unix and Linux handle the shebang. [`#!`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) must be the *first two bytes* in the file. If you have a BOM then this isn't true anymore hence the error.

Note that putting a BOM is completely useless from the point of view of the python interpreter, since the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` already tells python the encoding.

AFAIK BOM is usually **not** used with utf-8. It is used for UTF-16 et similia in order to specify the byte-order. If the editor assumes the wrong encoding you should be able to explicitly open the file with the correct encoding.

Comment: Indeed, according to the Unicode standard, "Use of a BOM is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8, but may
be encountered in contexts where UTF-8 data is converted from other encoding forms that
use a BOM or where the BOM is used as a UTF-8 signature."

Comment: The risk is high for unaware programmers to make the mistake with Notepad++ though, as what the editor presents as the *default* UTF8 encoding (simply named "UTF-8") is actually a "risky" encoding using the BOM.

Comment: @Sebastien Notepad++ is a *Windows* program. If you want to produce cross-platform code with an editor that is well known to be part of a closed system you *must* test the code on all configurations, since the editor wont care for such details to make code portable. This is true even when using more open softwares that try to be cross-platform.

Comment: @Bakuriu A test *should not* be a must. And whether the system is closed here is irrelevant. One should test against the interface from a specification, rather than an implementation. Plus the exhaustive tests may be not implementable for unknown amount of configuration combinations. Only when in doubt of meeting a buggy implementation not satisfying to the assumption granted by the specification (or the standard), the test is definitely needed: to identify there is really a bug in the program you use, but not of yourself. Otherwise, test is often the last sorts in the method of verification.

Answer (score 5):

The cause of the problem is that my file was encoded using **UTF8 with BOM (Byte Order Mark).**

Removing the BOM, i.e. encoding the file using UTF8 without BOM solves the issue.

NB: for Notepad++ users, "UTF8 without BOM" is also called (weirdly) "ANSI as UTF-8" in the editor.

Comment: This is even mentioned in the Unicode FAQ: http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom5