# Execute sh file with Russian or Chines Chars - Saved as UTF-8 or Unicode

Tags: bash, encoding, character-encoding, locale

I have a file which has some Russian chars in it. Below is the content of my sh file.

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i "s/\bVAR1\b/Привет, как ты/g" file1.txt
```

When I save this file I had to save this as UTF-8 or Unicode format as I have some Unicode format characters in the file and I will loose those if I save as ANSI. Once I save the file, when I use the file command I get the below

```
bash-4.1$ file test.sh
test.sh: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) English text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

Question: how can I make this as executable shell script file? I get the below if my file has only English chars

```
bash-4.1$ file test2.sh
test2.sh: POSIX shell script text executable
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065522/shebang-executable-not-found-because-of-utf-8-bom-byte-order-mark

Comment: The real question here is "why should I not use some braindead Windows editor".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the hash sign (`#`) at the beginning of your shebang. Creating a file with this content (test.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh 
sed -i "s/\bVAR1\b/Привет, как ты/g" file1.txt
```

and then making it executable with `chmod +x test.sh` produces an executable script as expected.

```
$ file test.sh
test.sh: POSIX shell script text executable, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, Thanks for your reply. Is there any specific editor or something you use to create the test.sh file? i tried the same._#!/bin/sh 
sed -i "s/\bVAR1\b/Привет, как ты/g" file1.txt_ and i saved it using notepad - Encoding as UTF-8. Then tried the file command to check the format of the file and got the below                                                                                                        
bash-4.1$ file test.sh
test.sh: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators                                 
i ran the chmod +x test.sh but still it shows the

Comment: I used vim on MacOS. This post details that it is likely a problem with the BOM. If there is an option to do UTF-8 without BOM that should be used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065522/shebang-executable-not-found-because-of-utf-8-bom-byte-order-mark

Comment: Thank you Marcus. It worked without BOM. BOM was the issue. You saved my day