# Shebang not honoured

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a python script which looks like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import ...
```

And can normally execute it with `python3 script.py` but can't do so doing this: `./script.py`.
The script is executable (755), has the correct character encoding and is in unix style (LF instead of CRLF).

When I run `/usr/bin/env python3` I get dropped into the python shell interpreter.

When executing the python script from `bash` the interpreter (for the script) is `bash`, when executing it from `zsh` the interpreter is `sh`.

It doesn't matter if I change the shebang to any of the following variants:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#!/usr/bin/env python
etc...
```

Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: Dump the first few bytes as hex. It's not unheard of for editors (especially Windows-y editors) to put a BOM on UTF-8 text, [which breaks shebangs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19065522/364696).

Comment: Please provide the run log including any errors. That may give people more of a clue.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that fixed it, thanks, never would've thought of that. I guess I also wouldn't have thought about looking at a hex dump.